# How can I add images to field instructions?

Tags: control-panel

I'd like to have images in my field instructions, but adding the Markdown code doesn't work, nor does HTML. Is there a way to include images and other HTML within?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works with standard markdown code...

```
![Alt text](/path/to/image.png)
```

You can use either a full URL, or a local path to the image.

Comment: This no longer appears to work in Craft 3.3 (presumably it changed in 3.0).

Comment: is there any other possibility?